# Choose specific origin from multiple git remotes

Tags: git

On my local repository `git remote -v` gives the following output.

```
origin  https://gitlab.com/***.git (fetch)
origin  https://gitlab.com/***.git (push)
origin  https://github.com/***.git (push)
```

Repo has 2 remotes but names are equal. How to push only to one of remote?
If I specify `git push origin branch` it still pushes to both remotes.
Also If I need to rename one of them how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can push to a url, `git push https://gitlab.com/example/repo branch`, see its docs, and you can unset individual keys in the config, see its docs, `git config --unset remote.origin.url .*theoneidontwant.*`.

Comment: Thanks. And how to rename one of origin here? Then I don't need to push to urls?

Comment: Delete the bad url then add it back under the right name; or just edit the config file, it's a common and simple format.